# How do you support multiple Android device configurations in sources?

Tags: android, ide, preprocessor, build-automation, google-play

After introducing latest changes in Android SDK and Android Market it's now more or less standard that one and the same application can have several builds, one let's say oriented to small screen devices, other one of tablets and probably another version for devices lacking or having some features like front camera, wi-fi, GPS and so on.

In elder times (when J2ME was still alive) - problem was resolved using so-called preprocessing directives specific to NetBeans. The same source could support multiple configurations, up-to ten or even more. Nowadays how it can be done?

Please share your experience how you used to resolve these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's now more or less standard that one and the same application can have several builds

I'm not sure how you're using the word "standard" here. It's certainly possible, is occasionally necessary, and IMHO isn't something you race to go use. If you really need it, fine, but everything you listed can be handled with a single APK. Personally, I'd reserve the multiple-APK route for things that normal configuration and feature management can't cope with, such as device-specific bugs.

> Nowadays how it can be done?

One approach is to use an Android library project for the common code base and use separate hosting projects for your configuration-specific code.

Comment: What to do if I'd like to make source branching in the same file/class?

Comment: @barmaley: Use an existing Java preprocessor or write your own, and dump your IDE.